# IF with OR that references a range of cells

Tags: excel-formula

I am not getting a positive when using the formula 
`=IF(H3=OR(Sheet2!I:I),"PK","not PK")`
Even when the value of H3 is in Column I on sheet 2.  I only get "not PK"

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: can you give us a proper example? what do you have in those cell references? a screenshot of your data? or a link

Comment: I think he needs something like `if(iserr(HLookup(H3,Sheet2!I:I,1,TRUE)),"not PK","PK")`.  Off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula instead.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet2!I:I,"="&H3)>0,"PK","NOT PK")
```

Basically it's counting how many times it finds a value equaling H3, and if that number is greater than 0, it reads "PK", otherwise "NOT PK".